# Babel (French) does not translate the theorem environment in Beamer class

Tags: beamer, theorems, languages, babel

I'm using the beamer class, with the following preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl,aeguill}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts}

\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

When I use the `proof` environment, the word `Preuve` appears in the document. This is the desired behaviour.

```
\begin{proof}
    ...
\end{proof}
```

Conversely, the `theorem` environment produces the header `Theorem`, which is not wanted.

```
\begin{theorem}
    ...
\end{theorem}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The `beamer` class alreads loads the packages `amsthm`, `amsmath` and `amsfonts`. Further, afaik babel defines `\proofname` to be `D\'emonstration`, though it can easily be changed.

Comment: Easiest solution: `\documentclass[french]{beamer}`. The `beamer` class uses the `translator` package for translating and it will pick up the global option and translate to French as expected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The beamer class uses the [`translator`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/translator) package for translation. Just specify the language to be used:

```
\uselanguage{French}
\languagepath{French}
```

Here's a complete minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\uselanguage{French}
\languagepath{French}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}
    Some text
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}
    Some text
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's even easier just to give the language as global option `\documentclass[french]{beamer}`. `translator` will pick it up and translate to French as expected.

Comment: @cgnieder this doesn't work: "Example" should read "Exemple", but it doesn't. I've found that `\documentclass{beamer}\uselanguage{French}\languagepath{French}` gives the expected results. Note that you must use both commands provided by Stefan Kottwitz, and that the capital F matters.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know, the `amsthm` package does not attempt to translate its theorem names. It's probably easiest to simply declare a new theorem environment with the `\newtheorem` command. On this note, it might also be worthwhile to check out the `ntheorem` package. It's quite similar to `amsthm` but newer and offers a few more formating options.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The solution I came up with for this involves a command called `\@if@EN@else@DA` using babel's `\iflanguage` in my `\newtheorem` commands. It's not in any way robust - in fact it's an ugly hack - but it does work