# Change "Theorem" to "Věta" in beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems, languages, naming, translator

I tried to use `\uselanguage{Czech}\languagepath{Czech}` as suggested in [Babel (French) does not translate the theorem environment in Beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12113/babel-french-does-not-translate-the-theorem-environment-in-beamer-class), but I still get "Theorem" instead of "Věta" for my theorem. How can I teach beamer the Czech words? And can I submit the language mutations to CTAN somehow to make the widely available?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\uselanguage{Czech}
\languagepath{Czech}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}
    Some text
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}
    Some text
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [How to rename theorem or lemma in beamer to another language](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38392/how-to-rename-theorem-or-lemma-in-beamer-to-another-language/38400#38400)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no Czech dictionary provided along with the `translator` subpackage of Beamer, so you need to help it; the proof name is changed, because `babel` knows about `\proofname`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\uselanguage{Czech}
\languagepath{Czech}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\deftranslation[to=Czech]{Theorem}{Věta}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}
    Some text
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}
    Some text
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I then copied `translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict` to `translator-theorem-dictionary-Czech.dict` in the current directory and changed the relevant line, obtaining the desired result even after removing the `\deftranslation` line, because the file was read, as shown by

```
(./translator-theorem-dictionary-Czech.dict)
```

in the log file.