# how to write théorème instead of theorem in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, languages

I am doing a math presentation in beamer. How can i have "théorème" written instead of "theorem" and "définition" instead of "definition" ?
This is what i have as of now :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\setbeamertemplate{theorems}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\author{}
\title{ccc}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\begin{document}
%\logo{} 
\institute{} 
\date{01/06/2014} 
%\subject{} 




\def\O{\mathcal O}
\def\Q{\mathbb Q}
\def\R{\mbox{$\mathbb R$}}
\def\Z{\mathbb Z}
\def\C1{\mathbb C}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12113/15925 help?

Comment: [how-to-rename-theorem-or-lemma-in-beamer-to-another-language](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38392/how-to-rename-theorem-or-lemma-in-beamer-to-another-language/38400#38400)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question if either of the above links can solve the problem.

Comment: Simply pass `french` as a class option: `\documentclass[11pt,french]{beamer}` and keep the loading of `babel`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
\uselanguage{*your language*}
\languagepath{*your language*}
\deftranslation[to=*your language*]{Theorem}{théorème}
\deftranslation[to=*your language*]{Definition}{définition}
```

works for me.

Comment: This is rather a comment than a solution -- your code contains `HTML` tags.